# Repentance from a misdeed: Is there a chance that Allah may forgive me?

Tags: sin, tawba

Assalamualaikum
My sin present on internet will Allah Forgive me

Answer (score 3):

First of all committing sins is rather human and there's no reason why you should punish yourself or harm yourself for a sin you've committed and repented from. Especially if you did all your best to relocate what you've done wrong.

Allah the almighty says:

- > **Do they not know that it is Allah who accepts repentance** from His servants and **receives charities and that it is Allah who is the Accepting of repentance**, the Merciful? ([9:104](https://legacy.quran.com/9/104))
- > And those who do not invoke with Allah another deity or kill the soul which Allah has forbidden [to be killed], except by right, and do not commit unlawful sexual intercourse. And whoever should do that will meet a penalty. (68)
  >   Multiplied for him is the punishment on the Day of Resurrection, and he will abide therein humiliated - (69)
  >   **Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them Allah will replace their evil deeds with good**. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful. ([25:68-70](https://legacy.quran.com/25/68-70))
- > Say, "**O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins**. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful." ([39:53](https://legacy.quran.com/39/53))
- > **And it is He who accepts repentance from his servants and pardons misdeeds**, and He knows what you do. ([42:25](https://legacy.quran.com/42/25))

So you should have faith in your lord and His acceptance of a true and sincere repentance. And you could do good deeds such as offering charity, helping others being good, performing nafl prayers or fast etc. to get closer to Allah and hopefully feel your guilt vanishing by each good deed more and more.

As for sincere repentance all you need to do is:

- Being aware that what you've committed is a sin and that being ashamed of it.
- Intending to stop the sinful act you've committed and actually stopping it at once (it is certainly good to leave everything behind you that reminds you of that act or any person that was involved with it).
- Intending not to do it again and asking Allah for forgiveness.

after this you should consider try to "keep the promise" and leave the sin with no return and try in future to reflect your daily deeds so that you may recognize the good ones and re-do them in future and the bad ones which you should avoid.

Allah the almighty says:

> O you who have believed, **fear Allah . And let every soul look to what it has put forth for tomorrow - and fear Allah** . Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what you do. ([59:18](https://legacy.quran.com/59/18))

Note that the verse quotes fear Allah twice (referring to taqwa) once before looking what you have put forth and once afterwards!

There's a rather weak narration reporting that 'Umar ibn al-Khattab said:

> **Take stock of yourselves before you are brought to account; weigh yourselves before you are weighed**, for that will make the Reckoning easier for you tomorrow, if you take stock of yourselves today and prepare yourselves for the great presentation on the Day when you will be be brought to Judgement, and not a secret of yours will be hidden.   (Source of the translation islamqa #[248273](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/248273/importance-of-reflection-and-taking-stock-of-oneself), where you may find more details about the authenticity of the narration and its sources)

See also [Need help understanding the sins hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49271/need-help-understanding-the-sins-hadith).