# Do I have to do this during ramadan?

Tags: halal-haram, ramadan

Sorry if this isn’t a good question but i’m genuinely curious, i have a boyfriend we’ve been dating for a while. But I know it’s haram. I’m planning on fasting the whole month during ramadan but I don’t know if it will be accepted or not since I talk to him. Do i have to stop talking to him during ramadan or can I still talk to him after the fast ends every night? Please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you marry him?

Answer (score 1):

Ramadan is a month to get closer to Allah and give up sinning. So whatever you do in secret, all the haram, give it up. The Prophet Muhammad (saws) said:

"Woe to him who found the blessed month of Ramadan and let it pass by without gaining forgiveness" [Sahih Bukhari].

You're basically wasting your Ramadan if you're still committing the same sin whilst fasting or going back to that sin after fasting. You should spend Ramadan as a time to getting closer to Allah and giving up the haram, not continuously committing it. Sinners repent during this month and change their ways after it. You know this relationship is haram, so please don't continue it.

Allah forbids haram relationships before marriage, so your best bet would be to:

1. Get married (if they're Ahlul Kitab)
2. Break up

**EDIT:** If he is a Ahlul kitab, he must ask you for marriage.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But would it break my fasts if i were to just talk to him casually?

Comment: @hi8162 No. But in Islam, a female is not allowed to talk to a male and vice versa.

Comment: 1. Get married (if they're Ahlul Kitab): A woman/female can't marry a man from Ahlul Kitab, this is haram.

Comment: @Medi1Saif you’re right, my mistake.

Comment: I didn’t know it is haram for a woman to marry (a christian or a jew) if he reverts to Islam. is that true?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you know that having a boyfriend is haram in Islam and recoginze it as a sin.

Therefore it should be evident to you that any interaction between the both of you is haram the whole year, not only in Ramadan.

If you stop communication with him, it shouldn't be for Ramadan only, but for the sake of Allah and out of fear of Allah's punishment and in hope for his forgiveness. Having that said I must add that this means that you should consider doing it the right way from the beginning, this means:

- stop the relationship (and sin) at once and recognize it as a sin,
- ask for forgiveness and repent to Allah sincerely,
- and intend not to do it again

If the person you were dating was a Muslim and has good intentions he'd do the same and maybe (or hopefully for you) do it the right way too and ask for your hand in marriage once he's ready for that. In case he isn't he must convert to Islam first.

See also:

- [Repentance from a misdeed: Is there a chance that Allah may forgive me?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51548/repentance-from-a-misdeed-is-there-a-chance-that-allah-may-forgive-me)
- [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin)